# MySql field types for simple terms

Tags: mysql, database

I am setting up a script that will grab certain terms from a couple websites and put them into my database, lets say flickr image titles, so one row would be

0 (index), apple (title of flickr image), date (date when I grabbed the image), flickr.com (website where the image was grabbed)

I am wondering what kind of filed types do I need in the mysql table?

the only one I know is the date will get the DATETIME but not sure about the others, do I even need an index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table images (
id int not null auto_increment primary key,
title varchar(50),
grab_date date(),
site varchar(100)
) engine = myisam;
```

Indexes choice depends on what kind of queries you'll use more frequently.

Comment: thanks for the speedy answer, can you just tell me the difference between the 50 and 100 for varchar?

Comment: I've just supposed the length that you could need. Adapt them to your goals. ;)